# Simple htaccess trick

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to make example.org/fish and get the tag, but however, my script get the tag wrong. Here is my htacess;

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?tag=$1
```

index.php

```
echo $_REQUEST[tag]
```

output

```
index.php
```

What is the correct way to get the tag name ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to disallow existing files and directories from your rules otherwise your rule runs 2nd time for `index.php` as URI and makes `tag` parameter as `index.php`.

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?tag=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Sure, I was just waiting the 10 min accept block to end ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?tag=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Then call tag in index.php as,

```
echo $_GET['tag'];
```